# How to change the CSS of node-red UI

Tags: node-red

how to change the colour,style of buttons,placing of buttons in the UI of node-red-contrib-ui.It shows only green colour on execution,how to change it

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the `dist` folder.

I've managed to find some treasures in it.

https://github.com/andrei-tatar/node-red-contrib-ui/tree/master/dist

Comment: Please be aware that the *node-red-contrib-ui* project has been taken over by the core Node-RED team and renamed to the *node-red-dashboard* (https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/). Currently (30/06/2016) the code is under going refactoring and updates ahead of the first release under the new name. If you are planning to use it for anything serious I would suggest you base any changes on the new version.